# Не понимаю в чем ошибка drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, изображения, resources, drawable

Значитс-с, пытаюсь скинуть картинки в drawable, а он подчеркивает их как ошибку и при каждом запуске приложения, запускает картинку(типо вот посмотри в этом ошибка, я так понял), при этом запустить приложение не выходит, он ссылается на ошибку:
The resource name must start with a letter
А в mainactivity.kt к картинке обращаться через drawable нельзя:
Classifier 'drawable' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `The resource name must start with a letter` вроде бы ясно даёт понять в чём проблема

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в названии, оно должно начинаться с буквы, я протупил сильна

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переименовать картинку и имя обязательно должно быть без пробелов. У вас хоть и состоит имя без пробелов но иногда бывают такие глюки

Answer (score -2):

Я если честно не разбираюсь в разработке приложений. Но попробую написать расширение .jpg
В (R.draweble.1.jpg)